# Should I use OutletCollections for setting delegate property of multiple textfields?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, iboutlet, iboutletcollection

Say, I've n textfields, now I have individual @IBOutlets for them. Generally, I'd set the delegate like following:

```
textfield1.delegate = self
textfield2.delegate = self
.
.
.
.
.
.
textfieldn.delegate = self
```

However, I can also use IBOutletCollection for the same.

so I can have something like the following:

```
for tf in textfields{
    tf.delegate = self
}
```

where textfields is `[UITextFields]`, an array of textfields.

I wanna know how it affects the performance of the code? Kindly specify for smaller and larger sets separately(like when n = 3, n = 10).
Further, what happens if I'm not using IBOutletCollection and just programmatically creating an array like the following. Would it impact the performance or would it be the same as before?

```
textfields = [textfield1,textfield2,textfield3,.......,textfieldn]
```

I understand that chances of having a larger n represents bad designing, but I'm just curious.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can benchmark it, but the performance difference is almost certainly inconsequential. I’d suggest using whatever is most elegant and is most easily maintained (for me, I’d lean towards the outlet collection) and don’t be seduced into premature optimization.

Comment: Thanks for the remark @Rob, I usually lean towards the outlet collection too as it results in lesser lines of code. Regarding premature optimization, the question  just popped into my head, however, I'd keep your advice in mind.

Comment: As you said, this smells like bad design. Most probably there needs to be a tableView/collectionView, instead of so many IBOutlets.

Comment: Like I said, I'm just curious. @Starsky

Comment: I think these are such small things that you won't notice a performance decline even on an iPhone 4S ) This is just iterating through a collection of objects and assigning a delegate to them. Even if you had 50 objects, that wouldn't be noticeable to the user. As Rob said, I would go for the most elegant and shorter code version you can come up. Something like: `textfieldsCollection.forEach({ $0.delegate = self })`